# Entity Framework 6 IdentityUser code first issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework, identity, asp.net-identity

I am new to EF so this has caused me so many problems.

I peeked the code for the IdentityUser shipped with EF and it looks like this:

```
public class IdentityUser : IUser
{
    public IdentityUser();
    public IdentityUser(string userName);

    public virtual ICollection<IdentityUserClaim> Claims { get; }
    public virtual string Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<IdentityUserLogin> Logins { get; }
    public virtual string PasswordHash { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<IdentityUserRole> Roles { get; }
    public virtual string SecurityStamp { get; set; }
    public virtual string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

I can't change that, it is the way it is.
My problem is that I am certain (100%) that a User should have a one to one relationship with **IdentityUserLogin** but this model shows a collection......

This is causing me no end of problems because I can not map this to my database at all.
The **IdentityUserLogin** model looks like this:

```
public class IdentityUserLogin
{
    public IdentityUserLogin();

    public virtual string LoginProvider { get; set; }
    public virtual string ProviderKey { get; set; }
    public virtual IdentityUser User { get; set; }
    public virtual string UserId { get; set; }
}
```

which you can see means that there is a many to one relationship that is expected, but the **LoginProvider** is the key for this model. I tried to map the **LoginProvider** and **UserId** as the key but now when I try to login, the user is never found.

Surely someone has had this issue and has solved it.
If you have, could you point me in the right direction?

Cheers,

/r3plica

Comment: The relationship between User and IdentityUserLogin should be one-to-many as designed. This just holds information for OAuth logins to various providers like Google and Facebook.  A user can have multiple of these accounts that they could choose to use for login.  The key for IdentityUserLogin is actually the combination of UserId, LoginProvider, and ProviderKey.  What exactly are you trying to map to in your database, and why are you trying to map to IdentityUserLogin instead of the User object derived from IdentityUser?

Comment: The problem is that I already have the database. I tried to use EF to create a clean database to see the table structure but as I said it created the table with the UserId as the Key and then added another column called User_Id as a FK. This is obviously wrong so it was not helping me with my existing database. Now you have told me it is a combination of all three, I can create the mapping for that and test it out. If it works, that will be cool :)